# How does the Combat Vigor feat's maximum healing work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, healing, hit-dice

The feat [Combat Vigor](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/combat-vigor-combat/) states the following:

> As a standard action, you can spend up to 1 vigor point per 3 Hit Dice you have (minimum 1) to regain 1d6 hit points per vigor point spent (maximum 7d6).

Does this imply you would need 21HD to be able to roll all 7d6? Or is this attempting to imply 1d6 is "free" and you only need 18HD to roll all 7d6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Combat Vigor caps at 7 dice for 21 HD.

While at first this seems strange because Paizo has not made official rules for *PC*'s leveling past 20 (although they recommend a couple methods for players interested, they're just not officially "supported" or, presumably, balance tested). However, there are a large number of creatures that could take this Feat that have at least 21 HD, and plenty that have 24+.

As written, any creature with 1-5 HD (which can be found in monster statblocks after their HP; IE the [Great Old One Cthulhu](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/great-old-ones/great-old-one-cthulhu/) has "hp 774 (**36d**8+612); fast healing 30") can spend a Stamina to gain 1d6 hp back. With their 6th HD they gain the option to spend more Stamina for more di(c)e, increasing every third HD until 21. At 21 it plateaus, so even Cthulhu could only spend 7 Stamina for 7d6 hp (instead of 12d6 for 36 HD).

Comment: This is correct. It might also be worth mentioning why this is the case from the RAW. The general rule is that you can spend up to 1 vigor point per 3 hit dice. If you have fewer than three hit dice, normally that would mean 0, however there is a specific case here that says the minimum of "1 vigor point per 3 hit dice" is 1, even if it would otherwise be 0. It seems like this might have been what OP was confused about.

Comment: That's not what I got from their question, but I could stand to add some details.